# Comparison of 180nm and 65nm CMOS technology in consideration of delay, power and energy consumption

Tags: power, cmos, energy, delay

how would each of them typically compare with respect to delay, power and energy consumption?
(Used in digital circuits)

Answer (score 2):

Above 180 -> 110 nm (depending upon whose process it is) you caould easily follow the scaling rules and get a rough order of magnitude.  However, moving to 65 nm and below, several significant changes take place that don't allow direct scaling based estimation to work.  Things like high K gate di-electric, Low K-dielectric in the BEOL (Back End Of Line).  You really need to compare data-sheets directly, and these are only available under NDA.